# Problem involving Scheffe's theorem and asymptotic distribution

Tags: self-study, uniform-distribution, asymptotics, order-statistics, iid

If $\{ X_n \}$ are independently and identically distributed $U(0,1)$ random variables and $V_n = n(1 - X_{(n)})$ (where $X_{(n)}$ denotes the $n$th or largest order statistic), then how do I derive the asymptotic distribution of $V_n$, using **Scheffe's theorem** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Start with the CDF of $X_{(n)}$ which is simply $x^n$.

CDF of $V_n$ is $$P\left(n(1-X_{(n)}) \leq v\right) = P\left(1-X_{(n)} \leq v/n\right) = P\left(X_{(n)} \geq 1-v/n\right)\\=1-P\left(X_{(n)} \leq 1-v/n\right)$$

Then use the CDF of $X_{(n)}$, take the derivative to get the PDF, and then use Scheffe's Lemma.

Also see related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313390/probability-density-of-the-maximum-of-samples-from-a-uniform-distribution

Comment: Welcome to our site - thanks for taking the time to typeset your math